# Communication from Raspberry Pi 3B to Pi zero 1.3 via USB

Tags: pi-3, usb, ssh, serial, pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B that I need to use to communicate to a Pi Zero 1.3.

I am able to SSH into the Pi 3B from my computer via ethernet.  I can also SSH into the Pi Zero from my computer via USB.  Unfortunately, I need to have the Pi Zero connected to the Pi 3B via a USB cable and so far I cannot seem to get them to communicate.

I was hoping to either use SSH or pyserial over the USB cable, but I'm not sure how to set up either option.  I was hoping to get some advice on how to proceed.  Note that I need to get them to communicate via the USB cable.

Here is a diagram showing what I am trying to do to help with clarity.
[image: System Diagram]

Is it possible to SSH into the Pi Zero from the Pi 3B over USB? Some of my googling has led me to believe that the USB hub on the Pi 3B only allows it to be a host and not a client (and in the scenario I am describing I think it needs to be the client).  Is this correct? If not, connecting to the Pi Zero via SSH would be my preference.

Additionally, when I was trying to SSH into the Pi Zero, I noticed that it seems to be trying to connect over the eth0 interface rather than the usb0 interface. If I do

```
ping raspberrypi.local -I usb0
```

to get the IPv4 Address, calling `arp` yields a new entry over the usb0 interface, but when I then call SSH (with or without using a bind_address) it adds an incomplete entry to the table which suggests to me it is trying to connect over eth0 even though the Pi Zero is on usb0.  Nevertheless, I do not have a lit of networking background so I could be completely wrong in this assumption.

Here is the arp table after doing what I described above
[image: arp table]

Note that I have Raspbian Stretch Lite installed on both Pis currently. I could change that if necessary, but I know that I do not want a GUI on either Pi.

Thank you!